# Order status and status log

Tags: php, database, database-design, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am developing a backend of e-commerce (online shopping) in PHP / MYSQL.

I want to know what the best way dealing with orders status and status tracking/date.

When a user placed an order, the order status will be 1 (`tbl_order.status = 1`) on the tbl_order table. Is this the best way?

Here are the numbers of order status:

- 1 - New Order
- 2 - Pending
- 3 - Cancelled
- 4 - Completed

When staff login on the backend, they can change the order status step by step.

I want to track who done it and the time, how can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current order status should be stored on the order table as you suggest.

But for tracking changes, I would suggest a separate log table, where you would log `timestamp`, `order_id`, `user_id`, `old_status`, `new_status`. This way you can retrace full history at any time (as opposed to `LastUpdate` concept).

This concept can be generalized beyond the order status - any field value changes can be tracked this way (though with lots of tracking log tables tend to grow in size rapidly)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion mkilmanas. Is old_status field necessary? Each order may have 4 status Eg: New Order -> Acknowledge -> Processing -> Completed (Step by Step from staff)

Comment: It doesn't hurt to have it. Especially if there will be irregularities in the process at some point (e.g. order is completed, but then canceled (returned), or someone accidentally marks it as processing and needs to have it reset back, and so on)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing fundmentally wrong with this method. Will you have an OrderStatus table that stores the numbers next to their meanings?  I would recommend this as it will allow for different statuses to be added in the future with a minimum of fuss.

With regards to tracking changes and time - you would usually have a "LastUpdated" and "UserId" column which is updated each time the order is modified (perhaps using a stored procedure to enforce this).  I'd put these in tbl_order table so that any changes to the order are logged.

Overall I think you're going down the right path.

Comment: In regarding to tracking - I need a list of tracking of each order. For example. What time has been "pending" and who assigned it and then what time "Completed" and "who". Do you think I should have order_logs table? First update tbl_order.status and then insert row into into order_logs ?